# How to logically code an ES6 promise inside a while loop

Tags: javascript, loops, es6-promise

This code calls a function (`getTable()`) that returns a promise:

```
function getTables() {
    while (mLobby.tblCount() < 4) {
        getTable().then(function(response) {
            mLobby.addTable(response);
        }, function (error) {
            console.error("getTable() finished with an error: " + error);
        });        
    }
}
```

It never resolves (and eventually crashes due to full memory) because of the clash of the async function call and the normal flow of the `while` loop.  I tried changing the `while` to an `if` with a recursive call, but that gave the same result:

```
function getTables() {
    if (mLobby.tblCount() < 4) {
        getTable().then(function(response) {
            mLobby.addTable(response);
            getTables();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why not calling you `addTable` function 4 times ? (Don't misread me, inside a loop)

Comment: I simplified for the question here.  The loop value isn't known before hand.

Comment: can you post the error log and getTable implementation ?

Comment: Your second approach with recursion is the way to go and should work, make sure that `mLobby.tlbCount()` returns the proper value. Also, is `mLobby.addTable()` a synchronous operation?

Comment: @karim... then it will be just like my last question that got locked due to allegedly being a duplicate.  It wasn't.

Comment: When the recursive code example does not work, this means that the function `mLobby.addTable` is itself not synchronous or that it does not increase `mLobby.tblCount`correctly.

Comment: I don't care any more.  Random comments are pointless.  The last question is where i needed the answer, as it has all my code.  But it's locked because... reasons.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, using Promises inside of a synchronous action like `while` won't work like you want.

What I've done is use `async await` to accomplish the same task. Something like...

```
 async function getTables() {
     while (mLobby.tblCount() < 4) {
         await getTable();
         // whatever other code you need...
     }
 }
```

So, the while loop will continue to work as expected only after each `getTable()` call is resolved. Definitely test this code, obviously.

Here's a really simple working example of what I'm talking about: https://codepen.io/alexmacarthur/pen/RLwWNo?editors=1011

Answer (score 3):

Is there a particular reason to do this in a while loop and adding the results to the lobby object while doing it?
Maybe you could use just a standard-for-loop that calls getTable 4 times:

```
function getTables(limit=4){
  let results = [];
  for(let i=0; i<limit;i++){
    results.push(getTable());
  }
  return Promise.all(results);
}
```

Your method will return a promise that will resolve with the array of the result of the given getTable-calls

```
getTables().then(tables => {
  tables.forEach(table => {
   if(myLobby.tableCount() < 4) myLobby.addTable(table)
  })
}).catch(console.warn)
```

Comment: I'm over it.  Silly software won't even allow me to delete this question.  This place makes it as hard as humanly possible to ask a question and get answers to it, and when I'm sick of it all and try to delete it so as not to waste any more time for anyone, it won't let me delete it.  Ridiculous place.

Comment: Nevermind, at least your problem seems to be solved. (Yeah, the restrictions are sometimes annoying)